# Como puedo remover todos los elementos que tengan la class "Sin guardar"?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Tengo una tabla **html** y algunas filas `tr` tienen la clase **Sin Guardar**.

¿Como puedo remover de la tabla **html** todos los elementos `tr` que tengan dicha clase?

No es remover la clase del elemento,sino , remover los elementos `tr`.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Comment: Supongo que lo quieres es algo como `$('.SinGuardar').remove()`, pero si no pones un [mcve] va a estar complicado aportar algo más

Answer (score 2):

En jQuery te lo dejo.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.singuardar').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Lo que haces es seleccionar todos los elementos con la clase singuardar y los eliminas uno a uno con `.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que no has puesto nada que hayas probado te doy una solución can javascript para hacer lo que necesitas.

Necesitas recorrer la tabla y comprobar si el tr tiene la clase que quieras eliminar. En el caso de que lo tenga necesitas usar .deleteRow() en la posición que este.

```js
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
     if(rows[i].className == "sin guardar")
     {
        document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
     }
}
```

```css
table, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="sin guardar">
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sin guardar">
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sin guardar">
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```